# SmartCapture: making pre-populated fields non-editable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, smart-capture

We created a SmartCapture form on a Marketing Cloud cloud page to be used for a data enrichment campaign. As part of the design, we have 2 pre-populated fields: physical address and account ID. Both of these are present in the form, but unlike other form fields such as name, surname, email, etc., these get pre-populated through AMPscript because we already have that data in the sendable data extension. Now, we would like to make those 2 fields non-editable ("read-only") fields, that would show the subscriber (prepoulated) information, but the information cannot be edited by the subscriber. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add "readonly" in the input tag. Here's an example:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" data-field-type="Text" value="%%=v(@firstname)=%%" readonly>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!!!